# How to create navigation view that is always visible on the side of a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I am creating a menu fragment that will have a drawer layout constrained on the left side. I keep getting the error: `DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`. After reading a lot of information on the web, I found that most answers said to have height and width set to 'match-parent'. After doing so, I still get the same error.

```
class MenuFragment : BaseFragment() {


    private lateinit var drawer: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_staff_menu_new, container, false)
        drawer = view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        view.findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav).setupWithNavController(findNavController())
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(requireActivity(), drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        return view

    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add the ```NavigationView``` as a direct descendant of the ```DrawerLayout```

Comment: I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

have your custom drawer class

```
public class AppDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {
    private boolean m_disallowIntercept;

    public AppDrawerLayout (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        // as the drawer intercepts all touches when it is opened
        // we need this to let the content beneath the drawer to be touchable
        return !m_disallowIntercept && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDrawerLockMode(int lockMode) {
        super.setDrawerLockMode(lockMode);
        // if the drawer is locked, then disallow interception
        m_disallowIntercept = (lockMode == LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
    }
}



<AppDrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!--We must define left padding for content-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/content_padding"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />

</AppDrawerLayout>
```

Handle padding for portrait and landscape:

values/dimens.xml -
0dp

values-land/dimens.xml -
300dp

and below is how you can lock the drawer :

```
   if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(0x00000000); // or Color.TRANSPARENT
        isDrawerLocked = true;
    } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(0x99000000); // default shadow
        isDrawerLocked = false;
    }
```